# foreach loop is not running the code inside

Tags: c#, .net

I recently got asked to look at one of our C# web forms that you could search off of and it is supposed to return the result from our db when the user searches. I am usually a node developer but code is code and the task was handed to me.

I found the method where the code was running and I saw these ugly nested foreach loops so I set some breakpoints and to my surprise one of my foreachloops was breaking out of the loop before running the code inside it. I thought well I found it but I am not sure why this behavior is happening.

below is my full method I even put a try/catch around the foreach loop that was breaking out but there was no exception being thrown. so in my debugger the part that says

```
foreach (var b in bids)
```

all the code inside this foreach loop never executes and I have no idea why. Please can someone help

```
static public object GetData(DataManager value, string customer, string subdivision, string status, string user, string date, string tags, string serviceType, string pricingType)
    {
        var lst = new List<Bid_Master>();

        using (var context = new BiddingDataContext(KP.Common.KPConnectionString))
        {
            context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

            var fdate = DateTime.Parse(date + " 00:00:00");
            var tdate = DateTime.Parse(date + " 23:59:59");

            var bids = context.Bid_Masters
                              .Where(x =>
                                        (x.Customer_ID == customer || customer == "-1") &&
                                        (x.Subdivision_ID == subdivision || subdivision == "-1") &&
                                        (x.Bid_Status == status || status == "-1") &&
                                        (x.Created_By == user || user == "-1") &&
                                        (x.Pricing_Type.ToString() == pricingType || pricingType == "ALL") &&
                                        ((x.Created_Date > fdate && x.Created_Date < tdate) || date == "01/01/2000") &&
                                        (x.Service_Type == serviceType || serviceType == "-1"))
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created_Date);
            try
            {
                foreach (var b in bids)
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tags))
                        lst.Add(b);
                    else
                    {
                        var arrtags = tags.Split(',');

                        var attrs = context.Bid_Master_Attributes.Where(x => x.BM_ID == b.BM_ID).ToList();

                        foreach (var attr in attrs)
                        {

                            foreach (var t in arrtags)
                            {
                                if (lst.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BM_ID == b.BM_ID) != null) continue;

                                var isDec = false;

                                decimal dVal = 0;
                                if (decimal.TryParse(t, out dVal)) isDec = true;

                                string sVal = t;

                                if ((isDec && attr.TagValueNum.HasValue && attr.TagValueNum == dVal) || sVal == attr.TagValueString)
                                {
                                    lst.Add(b);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        var enumerable = lst.AsEnumerable();
        Syncfusion.JavaScript.DataSources.DataOperations operation = new Syncfusion.JavaScript.DataSources.DataOperations();




        if (value.Sorted != null && value.Sorted.Count > 0)
        {
            enumerable = operation.PerformSorting(enumerable, value.Sorted) as IEnumerable<Bid_Master>;
        }
        if (value.Where != null && value.Where.Count > 0) //Filtering
        {
            enumerable = operation.PerformWhereFilter(enumerable, value.Where, value.Where[0].Operator) as IEnumerable<Bid_Master>;
        }
        int count = enumerable.AsQueryable().Count();
        if (value.Skip != 0) //Paging
        {
            enumerable = operation.PerformSkip(enumerable, value.Skip) as IEnumerable<Bid_Master>;
        }
        if (value.Take != 0)
        {
            enumerable = operation.PerformTake(enumerable, value.Take) as IEnumerable<Bid_Master>;
        }

        return new
        {
            result = enumerable,
            count = count
        };
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked what `fdate` and `tdate` end up being? Or, that bids actually has any results?

Comment: Are you sure that `bids` contains elements? It's possible that the query may not return anything and that `bids` ends up being an empty collection.

Comment: @sedders123 That was my first thought as well.

Comment: You should get rid of the `catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }` - it's a very bad idea in any C# code - but especially so on a web form. This is just sweeping errors under the rug. It's a great way to create buggy code that's extremely hard to debug.

Comment: how about adding `Debug.Writeline(bids.Count());` right before the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bids list is not having any items to loop through. Try to run the query  directly in the Database and check whether any output is coming or not.

Comment: If your answer starts with "I think" then it probably should be a comment. If you know for sure, then write it that way and leave this as an answer.

Comment: you guys are right after deciphering this in visual studio bids doesn't have a result the user that I am passing in has a value of 3366 which wouldn't return anything on the db because it is a name..... trying to figure out why date isn't returning anything now but that is exactly what it is bids is empty

Comment: Great. You found the root cause. We are on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Boy that code is ugly. The only "jump" line that would do what you described (I assume you understand `if` statements) I found was here

```
 foreach (var t in arrtags)
 {
      if (lst.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BM_ID == b.BM_ID) != null) continue;
```

The `continue` statement means: "Skip to the next iteration of the loop". In this case, the next element in `arrtags`.

If *all* the code in the `foreach` is not running (not just part of it) make sure `bids` is actually populated.